# Errors when installing Maven on Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, windows, maven, intellij-idea, cmd

I have a problem, I want to install Maven to Intellij IDEA on the following [instructions](https://habrahabr.ru/post/77382/), but in the end I have errors, how can I fix them? :(

```
C:\Users\Alex_msi>mvn -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible initial and maximum heap sizes specified
"cmd" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Comment: Just for reference: the text says `"cmd" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: See the answer from Federico, you have customized VM options somewhere and Xms value is larger than Xmx which is not allowed by JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Just by looking at the error given to you by the VM, i suggest you to check the -Xmx and -Xms arguments. Might as well be that they are wrongly configured (for example, you could have set a minimum heap size which is actually bigger than the default maximum one or vice versa).